# Installation of CentOS 8.2

Tags: installation, centos

We have a bunch of workstations installed on CentOS 7.4. We want to start implementing the switch to CentOS 8 but it's already not going as planned.

First, I generate my usb installation with this command:

```
sudo dd if=/path/CentOS-8.2.2004-x86_64-dvd1.iso of=/dev/sdc
```

And I've verified the checksum of the iso.

From the CentOS installation menu, we choose **Install Centos 8.2...** and no matter what type of installation we choose (EFI or Bios), we always get the following error:

```
dracut-pre-udev[885]: modprobe: FATAL: Module floppy not found in directory /lib/modules/4.18.0-193.el8.x86_64
dracut-pre-udev[885]: modprobe: ERROR: could not insert 'sha256_mb': No such device
[ ok ] Started Show PLymouth Boot Screen.
[ ok ] Started Forward Password Requests to Plymouth Directory Watch.
[ ok ] Reached target Local Encrypted Volumes.
[ ok ] Reached target PAths.
```

And then nothing else ever happens even if the machine still on.

However, if in the CentOS installation Menu, we choose **Troubleshooting** and then **Install CentOS Linux 8 in basic graphics mode**, we are able to perform the installation.

How could we solve this? We need to be able to run basic installation for the deployment, previously done with tftp and kickstart.

EDIT:
Increasing log level to debug doesn't provide any additional log.

Comment: add modprobe.blacklist=floppy to the kernel options

Comment: Adding this by pressing tab on the installation menu entry didn't work. It's what I was suppose to do, right? Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and same error message, this seems related to fips.
Adding fips=0 on kernel command line fixed it in my case.